# How do you add multiple items into one spot in a stack array?

Tags: java, arrays

How do you add multiple items into one spot in a stack array?

For instance, if I was trying to get information for a rectangle into array[0] (and I already was given the information; like length = 1; width =24; coordinates (1,2) [or something like that]) how would you go about putting all of that information into a single slot in an array?  This is using a singleDimensional array, by the way.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more clear on what you mean by adding multiple items into one slot. Do you want to add all the items (coordinates in this case) and store it in one element of the array?

Comment: That's what I was instructed to do.  All of the items should be placed in arraySlot[0]

Answer (score 0):

Into a single slot, you can't do that. Array slots can only hold one value, and that's it. I would suggest making it an array of java.awt.Rectangle or just make it a two dimensional array.

Comment: For the homework assignment, the teacher wants us to do something where we add all that information into a single-dimensional array.  Store it.  The alter it later.  I'm unsure why, it doesn't make much sense to me.  I've used two-dimensional arrays for things like this, but he doesn't want us to do so.

Comment: @RachelMoss so use a single dimensional array of RectangleInfo classes which will keep your parameters (length, width, ...) See my answer.

Comment: You could use the RecangleInfo thing that he wrote, or you can save memory for the user and just use the Rectangle class in the awt package

Answer (score 0):

> ...putting all of that information into a single slot for an array?

You have several descriptor values for an entry in your array. Use a structure for keeping these parameters (e.g. length = 1; width =24; coordinates (1,2)) and define your array as a list of instances of this structure. I mean write a `RectangleInfo` class to keep these parameters and use an array of `RectangleInfo` objects.

Example usage:

```
// The template structure to keep your rectangle variable parameters.
class RectangleInfo
{
    public int length, width;
    public int[] coordinates;
    RectangleInfo(int length, int width, int[] coordinates)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }
}
```

And in your main method implement something like this snippet:

```
public static void main ( String [] args )
{
    RectangleInfo rInfo1 = new RectangleInfo( 10, 20, new int[]{1,2});
    RectangleInfo rInfo2 = new RectangleInfo( 60, 50, new int[]{9,8});

    RectangleInfo[] array = new RectangleInfo[5];
    array[0] = rInfo1;
    array[1] = rInfo2;

    System.out.println("2nd Rect's y coordinate: " + array[1].coordinates[1]);
}
```

Comment: Oh! Okay, that makes more sense! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an array of rectangles. i would create a class that had the "information" you need for one single rectangle, and then in the main function, create an array of those classes that you just created. for exqmple, if the object ou created was called MyRect, in main you would say MyRect [] array = new MyRect[12]. and then you could fill those elements with new instances of MyRects.